# Can I get xpath count value in robot framework

Tags: xpath, robotframework

Assume the following XML:

```
<data>
    <node id="1" />
    <node id="2" />
    <node id="12" />
    <node id="16" />
</data>
```

This xpath expression should be valid:

```
count(//node)
```

.. and should produce the number 4

I'm new to robot frameworks. Is it possible to use this xpath in robot framework?
for example something like:

```
${value}=  Get something something   source=${xml}    xpath=count(//node)
```

The one below works but I would like the xpath to produce the end value, not a list.

```
@{nodelist}=         Get Elements    ${xml}  xpath=node
Length Should Be    ${nodelist}      4
```

**Edit**

I know that I can count the nodes in a list of nodes. However, I would like to get the absolute value (integer or string) using xpath. Now I need to write different code depending on if the xpath result is a node, list or attribute when the xpath could theoretically produce the final value.

Comment: There is `Get Element Count` keyword

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Get Element Count` Keyword it returns the number of elements matching the locator

You can do something as simple as this

```
${count} =  Get Element Count   name:div_name
Should Be True  ${count} > 2
```

For more info on Keywords Have a look at this [Keyword Page](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Element%20Count)

Answer (score 1):

When working with XML it is generally best to use the XML library. In the below example you'll find a solution for counting the elements using the XML library `Get Element Count`.

**data.xml**

```
<data>
    <node id="1" />
    <node id="2" />
    <node id="12" />
    <node id="16" />
</data>
```

**Testcase.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Library   XML
Library   OperatingSystem    

*** Test Cases ***
TC
    ${xml}      Get File    ./data.xml
    ${count}    Get Element Count    ${xml}    xpath=node
    Should Be Equal As Integers    ${count}    ${4}
```